# ASP Crystal Report The report has no tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to make a program where I put the data of a Datatable in a Crystal Report. Here is the code:

```
ReportDocument report_doc = new ReportDocument();
report_doc.Load(Server.MapPath("Trtp.rpt"));

string[] columns = new string[] { "col1", "col2", "col3", "col110", "col111" };

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
int count = columns.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   dt.Columns.Add(columns[i], typeof(string));

myConnection.comm.CommandText = @"select col1,col2,col3.col110,col111 from TabledataT where " + query;
myConnection.reader = myConnection.comm.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(myConnection.reader);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
report_doc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report_doc;
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

In the aspx page :

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
```

Trtp.rpt I have selected blank
[image]

Error is on this line

```
report_doc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
```

Error :

```
The report has no tables
```

This is the first time I am trying to create the program which uses crystal report, so dont have much knowledge about it.

Why I am getting this error ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try adding data table to data set before you fill datatable? mean first add the data table to data set than add it to data set

Comment: I tried, but the same error!!

Comment: problem is it could be multiple reasons. If report is not designed right, you will get this error, if there is any problem with data source you will get this error. Try merging data-table in data set instead of adding it, like ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt); and also try to check ds.tables.count if there is any

Comment: @Angloos, Do I need to configure anything in the `Trtp.rpt` file since I just added it without doing anything on the report. So, could that be the problem ? Do I need to create any table in `Trtp.rpt` ?

Comment: hmm depends what you wana do with it. If its just displaying data-table data, this should be straight forwards the way you are doing it.

Comment: @Angloos, When I put a datasource on `Trtp.rpt`, then I didn't got any error. But I want to get the data from the Datatable not from the datasource of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the working program. I need to create a dataset page with datatable with columns in it. Now Bind the Dataset to the Crystal report to make it working.